# VueJS - How to make a radio button checked if the id matches a value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have objects (products) in an array. Each product has its own rating and the rating is a number that comes from the database. I display the rounded average rating of each product on the product itself.

```
{{ Math.round(Object.values(product.rating)[0]) }}
```

I would like to display the average value in the stars (radio buttons) that people use to rate a product with. If I click to rate a product then the number of stars that match the current rating should be checked. On an individual product I can just use `v-model` but what do I do if it's a bunch of products in a list and each product has a different rating?

The values that I have for each radio button are the ID and the value attribute. How do I match the radio button's id or value with the current rating of the product?

There is no `this` so I tried doing this but it obviously does not work:

```
<div class="rating">
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="5"
    id="5"
    :checked="
    this.value ==
    Math.round(Object.values(product.rating)[0])
    "
    @change="rateproduct"
    /><label for="5">☆</label>
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="4"
    id="4"
    @change="rateproduct"
    :checked="
    this.value ==
    Math.round(Object.values(product.rating)[0])
    "
    /><label for="4">☆</label>
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="3"
    id="3"
    @change="rateproduct"
    :checked="
    this.value ==
    Math.round(Object.values(product.rating)[0])
    "
    /><label for="3">☆</label>
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="2"
    id="2"
    @change="rateproduct"
    :checked="
    this.value ==
    Math.round(Object.values(product.rating)[0])
    "
    /><label for="2">☆</label>
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="1"
    id="1"
    @change="rateproduct"
    :checked="
    this.value ==
    Math.round(Object.values(product.rating)[0])
    "
    /><label for="1">☆</label>
</div>
```

I tried doing this but it also does not work:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  value="5"
  id="5"
  :checked="
  Math.round(Object.values(post.rating)[0])
  ? 'checked'
  : ''
  "
  @change="ratePost"
  /><label for="5">☆</label>
</input>
```

Here is what I want to accomplish but it's not working and only the last post rating is selected

```
<template>
    <div class="postsList">
        <div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <div class="title">Title: {{post.title}}</div>
            <div class="currentrating">Rating: {{post.rating}}</div>
            <div class="vote">
                <div class="rating">
                    <div class="star" v-for="index in stars" :key="index">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="stars"
                            :value="index"
                            v-model="post.rating"
                            @change="ratePost"
                        /><label>☆</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'
    const stars = 5;
    const posts = ref([
        { id:1, title: "post1", rating: 2 },
        { id:2, title: "post2", rating: 3 },
        { id:3, title: "post3", rating: 2 },
        { id:4, title: "post4", rating: 5 },
        { id:5, title: "post5", rating: 2 },
        { id:6, title: "post6", rating: 1 },
        { id:7, title: "post7", rating: 2 },
        { id:8, title: "post8", rating: 3 },
        { id:9, title: "post9", rating: 4 },
        { id:10, title: "post10", rating: 1 },
    ]);
</script>

<style scoped>
  .post{
    padding:10px;
  }
  .rating{
    display:flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .title{
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .currentrating{
    margin-bottom:10px
  }
</style>
```

Comment: some hints: use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#radio), create a [v-for loop](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-for) for your radio inputs and bind your values dynamically, validate `checked` as a method or computed property to clean up your template area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution:

[image]

[Vue SFC Playground Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Average Star Rating</legend>
        <div class="radios">
            <div class="radioGroup" v-for="index in MAX_VALUE" :key="index">
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="stars" 
                    :value="index" 
                    v-model="starValue" 
                    @click.prevent=""
                />
                <label>{{ index }} {{ starText(index) }}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            Average Rating: {{  roundedAverageValue }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Individual Item Ratings</legend>
        <div v-for="(slider, index) in sliderValues" :key="index" >
            <label for="slider.name" class="sliderLabel">{{ slider.name }}</label>
            <input 
                type="range" 
                name="starSlider" 
                :min="MIN_VALUE" 
                :max="MAX_VALUE" 
                v-model="slider.value"
            >
            Value: {{ slider.value }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Average: {{ averageValue }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch, computed } from 'vue';

const MIN_VALUE = 1;
const MAX_VALUE = 5;

const starValue = ref(1);
const sliderValues = ref([
    { 
        value: MIN_VALUE,
        name: 'Item 1',
     },
     { 
        value: MIN_VALUE,
        name: 'Item 2',
     },
     { 
        value: MIN_VALUE,
        name: 'Item 3',
     },
     { 
        value: MIN_VALUE,
        name: 'Item 4',
     },
]);

const starText = (index) => {
    return index > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star';
}

const averageValue = computed(() => {
    let sum = 0;
    sliderValues.value.forEach((sv) => {
        sum += parseInt(sv.value);
    })
    return sum / sliderValues.value.length;
});

const roundedAverageValue = computed(() => {
    return Math.round(averageValue.value);
});

watch(roundedAverageValue, (newValue) => {
    starValue.value = newValue;
})
</script>

<style scoped>
fieldset {
  margin: 20px 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.radioGroup {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.radioGroup label {
    display: block;
}

.sliderLabel {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
</style>
```

Explanation:
This creates the radio inputs using v-for going from 1 to 5: `v-for="index in 5"`.  The value of each radio is the int index of the for loop. The model for all the radios is the same, `starValue`

I then use an array of objects to create my sliders, and using computed properties to get an average and a watcher on the computed property to change the radio's model value (since it is bad practice to have side-effects in a computed property).

---

Note that the code that you have recently posted has a bug in this part of your template code:

```html
<div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <div class="title">Title: {{post.title}}</div>
    <div class="currentrating">Rating: {{post.rating}}</div>
    <div class="vote">
        <div class="rating">
            <div class="star" v-for="index in stars" :key="index">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="stars"
                    :value="index"
                    v-model="post.rating"
                    @change="ratePost"
                /><label>☆</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This line: `name="stars"` is the same for each iteration of the outer v-for loop, meaning every single radio input you create is the and same radio ***group***. And since a radio group can show only one selection at a time, only one star is shown to be selected.

The solution is trivial: give each collection of stars a unique name property for the radio input. You would need to bind the name property and can use the post.id for uniqueness, So change this:

`name="stars"`

to this:

`:name="stars + post.id"`

and your posted code should work.

For example:

```html
<div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <div class="title">Title: {{post.title}}</div>
    <div class="currentrating">Rating: {{post.rating}}</div>
    <div class="vote">
        <div class="rating">
            <div class="star" v-for="index in stars" :key="index">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    :name="stars + post.id"
                    :value="index"
                    v-model="post.rating"
                    @change="ratePost"
                /><label>☆</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## New Iteration, now with Stars

The latest iteration of my answer now creates an individual rating panel that shows 5 stars hover-effect and which will fill all stars up to and including the rating selected. To achieve this, I had to change from using `input[type="radio"]` to using `input[type="checkbox"]` It then allows other components to use this component, passing in the panel's title as a prop and its value as a `v-model`.

[image]

## RatingPanel.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="star-panel">
    <fieldset class="flex-row">
      <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
      <div class="radio-wrapper">
        <div class="radios">
          <div class="radioGroup" v-for="star in stars" :key="star.value">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="stars"
              :value="star.value"
              v-model="star.checked"
              :id="title + star.text"
              @change="selectedItem(star.value)"
            /><label class="star-label" :for="title + star.text">
              {{ starChar(star.checked) }}</label
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-display">Rating: {{ stars[value - 1].text }}</div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(["title", "modelValue"]);
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);
const value = computed({
  get() {
    return props.modelValue;
  },
  set(value) {
    emit("update:modelValue", value);
  },
});

const stars = ref([
  {
    text: "1 stars",
    value: 1,
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    text: "2 stars",
    value: 2,
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    text: "3 stars",
    value: 3,
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    text: "4 stars",
    value: 4,
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    text: "5 stars",
    value: 5,
    checked: false,
  },
]);

const selectedItem = (index) => {
  value.value = index;

  stars.value.forEach((star) => {
    star.checked = index >= star.value;
  });
};

const FILLED_STAR = String.fromCharCode(9733);
const EMPTY_STAR = String.fromCharCode(9734);

const starChar = (checked) => {
  if (checked) {
    return FILLED_STAR;
  } else {
    return EMPTY_STAR;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  value.value = props.modelValue;

  stars.value.forEach((star) => {
    star.checked = props.modelValue >= star.value;
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<style scoped>
.star-panel {
  max-width: 400px;
}
.star-label {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: orange;
}

.star-label:hover {
  color: rgb(173, 113, 2);
  font-weight: bold;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.radio-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.radios {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.radioGroup {
  margin: 2px 15px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
</style>
```

Then the component that holds multiple RatingPanels:

## MultipleRatings.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="post-list" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <SingleRatingPanel :title="post.title" v-model="post.rating" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import SingleRatingPanel from "./RatingPanel.vue";

const posts = ref([
  { id: 1, title: "Post 1", rating: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: "Post 2", rating: 3 },
  { id: 3, title: "Post 3", rating: 2 },
  { id: 4, title: "Post 4", rating: 5 },
  { id: 5, title: "Post 5", rating: 2 },
  { id: 6, title: "Post 6", rating: 1 },
  { id: 7, title: "Post 7", rating: 2 },
  { id: 8, title: "Post 8", rating: 3 },
  { id: 9, title: "Post 9", rating: 4 },
  { id: 10, title: "Post 10", rating: 1 },
]);

// to demonstrate efficacy:
watch(
  posts,
  (newValue) => {
    newValue.forEach((p) => console.log(p));
  },
  { deep: true }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate you taking the time to help me with my issue. I will implement what you suggested and will give my feedback asap

Comment: How will this work for a list of posts? Because I don't see the logic of v-model on a radio if there are many posts each with it's own rating. Just trying to understand how it will function?

Comment: @crawlingdev: the radios all share the same v-model: `v-model="slider.value"`. All that is needed is that when a list's rating is changed, the average of the rating be placed in this model, as exemplified by my [mre] post above. If this still doesn't work for you, then you should post your own [mre] in your question -- a small runnable program that is small enough to be allowed by site software, that we can directly copy, paste, run and test.

Comment: I have 10 posts, each with 5 radios so that makes 50 radios all sharing the same v-model. How in logical terms is post1 and post10 going to have different ratings? Well how is any one of the posts going to have a different rating from the rest if there is just one v-model? Just trying to understand the logic that's all. I need to bind each post's set of radios to the post's average rating. Not worried about the rounding of the average I can do that in the back end and just send the rounded number to the front.

Comment: @crawlingdev: again, please create and post a [mre] so that I / we can fully understand your problem. I have put in the effort to create a small program that can be copied-pasted and run and that demonstrates a potential solution, I don't think that it is asking too much for you to do the same, especially since it is you who is asking for help. Please put in the small effort to help others help you.

Comment: @crawlingdev: But from what I *think* you are saying (can't be sure without that code), then probably each group of 5 radios would share a model, and likely a vue component. Your model would be an array of these.

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I want to accomplish but it is not working and only the last post have the right radio button selected

Comment: @crawlingdev: you've got a bug in your posted code in that you're putting all your radio inputs into the one and the same radio group, `name="stars"`. Please see the edit to my answer, the addition at the end.

Comment: @crawlingdev: please see edit to answer and posted code. Now using stars

Comment: Thank you so very much for this it's perfect and I am very grateful for the work you did on this.